# laravel filter on relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

hi i have this relationships with these 3 models

Customers

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customers extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'contr_nom',
        'contr_cog',
        'benef_nom',
        'benef_cog',
        'email',
        'polizza',
        'targa',
        'iban',
        'int_iban',
        'cliente',
    ];

    public function claims()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Claims::class);
        }
        
    public function refunds()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Refunds::class, Claims::class);
    }

}
```

Claims

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Claims extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'dossier',
        'date_cla',
    ];

    public function refunds()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Refunds::class);
        }           
        
    public function customers()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Customers::class,'customers_id');
        }           

}
```

and Refunds

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Refunds extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'date_ref',
        'status_ref',
        'disactive',
    ];

    public function services()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Services::class)
                ->withPivot(['services_id','services_amount','services_status']);
        }       
        
    public function claims()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Claims::class,'claims_id');
        }           

}
```

i have this in the controller (part of the code)

```
    $data =  Claims::with(array('customers'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','contr_nom','contr_cog','targa','email','gcliente');
    }))->get();
```

it works, i can get customers information (parent table) for each dossier ( i put in a datatables)
But i cannot insert another filter based on Refunds table.
I need to show only dossiers where

```
['status_ref', '>',4]
```

the problem is that status_ref is in Refunds table

i tried to do somthing like this but no works

```
    $data =  Claims::with(array('customers'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','contr_nom','contr_cog','targa','email','gcliente');
    }))->refunds()
    ->where('status_ref', '>',4)
     ->get();
```

I cannot understand why....
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  `whereHas` like:

```
$data =  Claims::with(array('customers'=>function($query){
           $query->select('id','contr_nom','contr_cog','targa','email','gcliente');
         }))
         ->whereHas('refunds', function (Builder $query) {
           $query->where('status_ref', '>', 4);
         })
         ->get();
```